# How to get form field value in onclick event

Tags: get, field, extjs

Please help me. how can I get user input.

```
Mytest.views.Forma = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {/*This is a panel which displays all*/

initComponent: function(){

    Ext.apply(this, {/*derive the form*/
        items: [ {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            id: 'formaFieldset',
            title: '',
            items: [
                {
                    name: 'from',
                    label: 'From'
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            cls: 'btnAction',
            text:'Price Check',
            handler:function(){
                //Here you need to print the values ​​of form fields            
                    }
                });
            }
        } ]
    });
    Mytest.views.Forma.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
}
  });

  Ext.reg('forma', Mytest.views.Forma);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use getValues() function to obtain the values in the form field.